# How to search for two similar images (memory game)

Tags: c#, xaml, compare, shuffle

i try to search for 2 similar images (like in a memory game)
i know how to do it, but it for sure is not the best way i guess...
anyone has a better solution?

here is the code how i have done it

```
private void first_button (object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)  //so button get pressed
    {
        field_one = true;

        StoryboardBack11.Begin();
        StoryboardBack11.Completed += new EventHandler(AfterAnimation);
        i = i + 1;
    }

// same for the other buttons

private void AfterAnimation(object sender, EventArgs e)    //check here after storyboard completed
    {if (i == 2)     // check after 2 clicks
        {
            i = 0;

            if (field_one == true && field_two == true)
            {
                if (imageUri_one.Equals(imageUri_two))
                    {
                        Fade_one.Begin();    //Storyboard starts
                        Fade_two.Begin();
                        field_one = false;
                        field_two = false;

                    }
            }

//and this for every possible combination 
//-> here is my problem because it is a lot to copy paste and thus not optimal i guess
            if (field_one == true && field_three == true)     
            {
                if (imageUri_one.Equals(imageUri_three))
                {
                    Fade_one.Begin();
                    Fade_three.Begin();
                    field_one = false;
                    field_three = false;

                }
            }
// here is the shuffeling of the images
private void test1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> Test = new List<string>();   //list of the images
        Test.Add("Art1.png");
        Test.Add("Art1.png");
        Test.Add("Art2.png");
        Test.Add("Art2.png");
        Test.Add("Art3.png");
        Test.Add("Art3.png");

        Test.Shuffle();   //they get randomly shuffled here and then realigned


        imageUri_one = Test[0];
        imageUri_two = Test[1];
        imageUri_three = Test[2];
            // ..... and so on


        // put the new image Uri to a button -> the same 6 time for everey button
        BitmapImage bm_one = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@imageUri_one, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        image11.Source = bm_one; //but it in xaml Source




}
```

so the thing is that i want to make the Uri flexible, so that i can shuffle different Uri when using another list and this should already work. but is there a more elegant way to check for similar images?
hope the question is clear :)

Comment: Don't use named variables for all button and imageUri. Use something like a two-dimensional array (representing the board) of custom objects (which contains the button and imageUri).

Comment: thats maybe better.. so one array for wether the button was pressed or not, and then another with the Uri's in it? and then compare the array-position of the Uri array, which is true in the true or false array? or something like that?

Comment: Something like that. But use one array, which contains element which are containing all information you need. So an array where every element has an IsPressed value, a URI value, and everything else you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo-code:

```
public class MyElement
{
    public bool IsPressed { get; set; }
    public string Uri { get; set; }
    ... anything else you want to know about that one tile
}
```

then build the logical board

```
MyElement[,] tiles = new MyElement[8, 8];
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        tiles[i, j] = new MyElement { IsPressed = false; Uri = whatever; ... };
    }
}
```

Now create the "physical" board with the buttons and assign a custom value for all buttons which contains it's coordinates.

Create one click handler where you check the tiles array for that coordinate and check it's MyElement object. Assign this click handler to all button click event.